Determine whether a point is in a boundary or not
I'm trying to solve a problem about Point and Boundary.
My problem:

I setup a Map where user can tap to pin a marker, whenever user pin a marker, I will send that marker LatLng server to check whether that marker is valid or not. "Valid" here means that it lies in the boundary ( which is a city / district that admin will specify in the admin page ) and I can do this with the API from Map service provides.
Is there anyway I can check this locally? Because I don't want to call API so many times (everytime user pin a marker ) I read about LatLng bounds but a district / city have many points ( many LatLong instead of a box from 4 LatLng). So there are 2 problems here I'm trying to solve, how can I find a boundary of a city / district, and how can I determine whether my marker lies in that boundary or not.

I'm trying to solve by using LatlngBounds but it seems this bounds usally use in 4 points

please add more info in your question

You can get the data of the city/district and save it in a GeoJSON format which is a common format for storing and sharing geographic boudnaries. OpenStreetMap, government GIS data, or other map services provide theGeoJSON data for city/districts.
for checking if a point is within a boundary i.e a polygon (a collection of points forming a boundary) city or district like:
const cityBoundary = {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [lng1, lat1],
      [lng2, lat2],
      ...
      [lng1, lat1] 
    ]
  ]
};

then you can use a point-in-polygon algorithm. You can use a lib like turf.js to check if a point is inside a polygon.
An example on how you could achieve this
// the point
const markerPoint = [markerLng, markerLat];

// Check if inside the polygon
const isInside = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(markerPoint, cityBoundary);

if (isInside) {
  console.log("The point is within the boundnary");
} else {
  console.log("The point is outside the boundary");
}


Some examples from the API documentation for the booleanPointInPolygon method https://turfjs.org/docs/api/booleanPointInPolygon#examples
